# What is the mistake in converting a byte array to bitmap in android? (the byte array is sent from a c/c++ server, android beeing the client)

Tags: android, c, sockets, opengl-es

I'm developing an android app that sends it's accelerometer and gravity sensor data to a c/c++ server which uses openGL library to make a 3D shape rotate on the screen. I want to send back to the android device "snapshots" from the OpenGL screen.

On the c/c++ (server side ) i do this :

```
//declarations
    struct PARAMS
{
    unsigned char Pic[4*256*256]; // 4 because of the GL_RGBA format
    char* msg;
};
PARAMS p;

// reading content of the screen
glReadPixels(0, 0, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, p.Pic);

//sending the data
send(sConnect,(char*)p.Pic,4*256*256,0);
```

On the android (client side) i'm trying to read the byte array and converting it into a bitmap.

```
//declarations
socket = new Socket("192.168.1.101", 1234);
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
private byte Image[]=  new byte[4 * 256 * 256 ];
private int IntImage[] = new int[4 * 256 * 256];
//read data which was sent from the server
dataInputStream.readFully(Image, 0, 256 * 256 * 4); // 



  //transform the byte array into int array
    // i'm doing byte & 0xFF to convert from byte to unsigned byte( java doesn't have unsigned           Byte)
    // I'm doing this to convert from GL_RGBA to ARGB_8888
    for (int i = 1; i < Image.length; i = i + 4) {
        int j = i - 1;
        aux = (Image[i + 3] & 0xFF);
        IntImage[j + 3] = (int) (Image[i + 2] & 0xFF);
        IntImage[j + 2] = (int) (Image[i + 1] & 0xFF);
        IntImage[j + 1] = (int) (Image[i] & 0xFF);
        IntImage[j] = aux;
 }

 //creating the bitmap:
 Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Config.ARGB_8888);
 bmp.setPixels(IntImage, 0, 256, 0, 0, 256, 256);

 //creating the image based on the bitmap
 imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

In this case the output is blank ( like a image just with transparent pixels)

If i do this :

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Image, 0,Image.length);
```

The `bmp` variable will always be null.

Any ideas of where I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have common endianness problem.

While using glReadPixels on little-endian or big-endian processor your results are different.

Please notice Java uses [network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking) (big endian). Same code written in C++ behaves different on PowerPC, arm (big endian) and x86_64 (little endian).

Comment: I converted the byte array that i'm sending from c++ and the byte array that i'm receiving in java/Android into int arrays, and the resault is the same. ( the data i'm sending is the data i'm receiving). Can this still  be a matter of endianness ?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your values in an array of type int. The Android format of ARGB_8888 is an array of bytes, each pixel getting 4 bytes, hence the "8888".

If you rewrote this to swap the values byte-by-byte instead of byte-to-int, it should work.

I've been working with something similar lately where I produce a file with ARGB_8888 data in it. (1 byte alpha + 1 byte red, 1 byte green, 1 byte blue pixels in the amount of width * height) If I put that in assets, read it into a byte[] array, and copy it into an ARGB_8888 bitmap of the right dimensions, it displays correctly.